# Wordpress plugin not eching popular posts

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, widgets, query-posts

I created a plugin in wordpress to show popular posts, but this is not returning the post and number of comments properly.

Even I have comments in my post(approved as well, so this is not the case) its displaying -

```
"No commented post this time!!";
```

Although If i put `echo` at this line around Line 78 - `$popular .= '</li>';`  it shows popular post, although I think there is something wrong still(either with logic or in code).

Debug option is set `true`
    define('WP_DEBUG', true);

My code -->

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Sw Popular Post Widget
Plugin URI: http://demo.test.com
Author: Swapnesh Kumar Sinha
Description: Go your Widget Section to check the widget. It is a general purpose plugin that creates a widget to limit the popular post display from 1 to 10 at front end of your site. Please leave your honest comments,suggestions, bugs etc regarding the plugin at my email id - "swapnesh20032003@gmail.com". The plugin is in working condition, tested at - WordPress 3.5.
########
INSTALL it via plugin section in your Wordpress Admin panel and then find it under APPEARANCE -> WIDGETS section.
######## 
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://swapneshsinha.wordpress.com
*/

class SwPopularPostWidget extends WP_Widget {

public function __construct() {
    //Widget actual processes
    $widget_options = array( 'Description' => 'Show Popular Posts' );
    parent::__construct( 'SwPopularPostWidget', 'Sw Popular Post Widget', $widget_options); 
}

public function form( $instance ) {
    //outputs the options form on admin
$instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'popularpostcount' => '','popularpostheading' => '' ) );
$popularpostcount = $instance['popularpostcount'];
$popularpostheading = $instance['popularpostheading'];
echo "Heading Title";   
echo "<input type='text' name='".$this->get_field_name('popularpostheading')."' id='".$this->get_field_name('popularpostheading')."' value='".$popularpostheading."' />";
echo "Number of post to show "; 
//echo "<select name='popularpostcount' id='popularpostcount'>";
echo "<select name='".$this->get_field_name('popularpostcount')."' id='".$this->get_field_name('popularpostcount')."'>";
    for( $i =1; $i<=10; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $i == $popularpostcount )
        echo "<option value='".$i."' selected>".$i."</option>";
        else
        echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
    } 
echo "</select>";
}

public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    //processes widget options to be saved
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['popularpostcount'] = $new_instance['popularpostcount'];
    $instance['popularpostheading'] = $new_instance['popularpostheading'];
    return $instance;
}

public function widget( $args ,  $instance ) {
    //outputs the content of widget
    extract($args);
    $popularpostcount = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['popularpostcount']);
    $popularpostheading = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['popularpostheading']);
    echo '<aside class="widget widget_meta" id="popular-2">';
    echo  '<h3 class="widget-title">'.$popularpostheading.'</h3>';
    echo  "<ul>";
    echo $this->popularPosts($popularpostcount);
    echo  "</ul>";
}


public function popularPosts($num)
{
     global $wpdb;

    $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 0 , $num");
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($posts);die;
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        $id = $post->ID;
        $title = $post->post_title;
        $count = $post->comment_count;

        if ($count != 0) {
            $popular  = '<li>';
            $popular .= '<a href="' . get_permalink($id) . '" title="">' . $title.'</a> '." - ".$count." Comments";
            $popular .= '</li>';
        }
        else
        $popular = "No commented post this time!!";
    }
    return $popular;
}


}

add_action( 'widgets_init' , create_function('', 'register_widget( "swpopularpostwidget" );' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

one possibility is:

```
public function popularPosts($num)
{
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'orderby' => 'comment_count', 'order' => 'DESC' );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($posts as $post):
        if($post->comment_count != 0 ){
            $count++;
        }   
    endforeach;
    if ( $count > 0 ):
        foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
            if($post->comment_count != 0 ){ 
                ?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> - <?php echo $post->comment_count; ?> Comments</li>
                <?php
            }
        endforeach;
    else :
        echo '<li>No commented post this time!!</li>';
    endif;
}


}
function swpopularpostwidget_init() {
    if ( !is_blog_installed() )
        return;

    register_widget('swpopularpostwidget');
    do_action('widgets_init');
}
add_action( 'init' , 'swpopularpostwidget_init');
```